# Xcode 8: set image render as to template image

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode8

In the previous versions of Xcode, one could change the way an image was rendered using this `window`:

[image: Window in previous versions]

However, I can't seem to find this same `window` in Xcode 8. How can I change the `Render As` setting these days? I know I can't change the devices by right clicking, but `Render As` doesn't seem to be listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up. It's now at the top of the screen, just under the image set's name:

[image]

Comment: Life saver! Thanks!